# Tree and its preorder traversal - Code error

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct Node  //Tree Node
{
    int key;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
}; 

int nodes[21], counter; //nodes[] array keeps all the nodes of the tree 
                        //in increasing order
                        //counter tracks the current index of the array

void preorder(Node* node){    //Preorder traversal of the tree
    if(node==NULL){
        return;
    }
    preorder(node->left);
    nodes[counter++]=node->key;
    preorder(node->right);
}

struct Node* createNode(int key){     //Tree Node Creation
    struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->key = key;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;    
}

void createTree(struct Node* newNode, struct Node* node){  //Creates a 
                                                     //binary search tree
    if(!node){
        node=newNode;    //Problem Line 
        return;
    }
    if(newNode->key<node->key){
        createTree(newNode, node->left);    
    }
    else if(newNode->key>node->key){
        createTree(newNode, node->right);    
    }
}

int main(){
    int node_count, node_value;
    struct Node* root = NULL;
    cout<<"Enter number of nodes"<<endl;
    cin>>node_count;
    cout<<"Enter node values in a space-separated format"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<node_count;i++){
        cin>>node_value;
        struct Node* newNode = createNode(node_value);
        if(!root){
            root = newNode;
        }
        else{
            createTree(newNode, root); 
        }
        cout<<root->left<<" "<<root->right<<endl;
    }
    counter=0;
    preorder(root);
    for(int i=0;i<counter;i++){
        cout<<nodes[i]<<" ";    
    }
    cout<<endl;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Above is the code for creating a BST and then storing its preorder traversal in an array. I have mentioned the problem line(the assignment of the pointer is not happening). Can someone, please help me out with this.

Comment: Lot of C in this. Recommend updating your reading materials.

Comment: Do you have any idea about `pointer` and `pointer point to pointer` ?

Comment: Reference to pointer would be a better choice here, I think, @JohnZeng . You should write up the answer. I'm stuck on a tablet and it sucks for writing anything complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning to a pointer is not going to affect the value after you return from the function.... Please read more about `pointer point to pointer` and [passing-arguments by reference in cpp](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/)

The following codes may solve parts of your problem, but not all, I believe there must be more problems in your codes but I don't wanna waste time to debug them.

```
void createTree(struct Node* &newNode, struct Node* &node){  //Creates a 
                                                     //binary search tree
    if(!node){
        node=newNode;    //Problem Line 
        return;
    }
    if(newNode->key<node->key){
        createTree(newNode, node->left);    
    }
    else if(newNode->key>node->key){
        createTree(newNode, node->right);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the help. Sorry about not adding a C tag. Also, please correct me if my following line is wrong: The added ampersand(&) ensures that the addresses in the actual pointers are modified rather than the addresses being modified simply in the local pointer copies created inside the function. If I wanted to modify only the values pointed out by the pointer, my earlier approach would have worked. But its better to do the suggested way. Are the previous lines correct (only if I have understood it correctly)?

Comment: If you wanna modify the value pointed out by the pointer, you should use `*` , so your earlier approach may get another error... My advice is you should read more and practice more on it.

Comment: The solution you told above solved the problem. I could input values and do a preorder traversal. It is printing correctly.  Got it. I will practice more. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do not assing any node to left and right pointers.
This should solve the problem.

```
void createTree(struct Node* newNode, struct Node* node) { 
    if (!node) {
        node = newNode;
        return;
    }

    if (newNode->key < node->key) {
        // if left node is null assign new node
        if (!node->left) {
            node->left = newNode;
            return;
        }
        else {
            createTree(newNode, node->left);
        }
    }
    else if (newNode->key > node->key) {
        // if right node is null assign new node
        if (!node->right) {
            node->right = newNode;
            return;
        }
        else {
            createTree(newNode, node->right);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I think this code should work... Just remove the stupid `node = newNode` at the third line.